# May I keep my copyright notice?

Tags: copyright-notice

I have a small business website.
I am using pictures with various licenses (license usage is correct).
At the bottom of my page I am showing a copyright notice "copyright © 2019 my business name".

Do I have to remove my copyright notice because I am not the copyright holder of all images on my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you may include a general copyright notice. You could more clearly identify what copyright claims you are making by adding something like:

> Site design and text copyright © 2019 BuisnessName.  Images copyright by their individual holders.

or

> Site design and text copyright © 2019 BuisnessName.  Image copyrights specified on individual images.

It is a good idea to provide attribution and an appropriate copyright notice on individual images. This can be done by adding a caption, in mouse-over text or in some other way that allows users to see it. In some cases the image license may require this.

Answer (score 1):

No, because you are claiming copyright of your website in its entirety, including the choice and arrangement of the images you have obtained.

You should probably, however, provide separate copyright/attribution statements for those images, as you can't claim copyright on the individual images.